# ASP.Net returning the page instead of the file requested to be downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a DataGrid in which I have a LinkButton. The LinkButton will display a file name and has its
CommadName and CommandArgument set so that the RowCommandFire(...) event will fire when the button is clicked.  The intention is to download a file linked by the LinkButton.
However, at Runtime - I am getting the page name such as filesViewPage.aspx being downloaded instead of the actual file requested to be downloaded.  I have the following code - but it is not downloading files as it should.  I have ensured IIS 7 MIME Types entry of "application/octet-stream" with the file extension ".*" - exists.

What is missing.  Please help...

---

```
 protected void RowCommandFire(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)    {
      if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
      {
        try {          
          Response.Clear();
          Response.ClearContent();
          Response.ClearHeaders();
          FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + e.CommandArgument);
          //byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToDownload.FullName);
          if (fileToDownload.Exists)  {
            string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileToDownload.Length.ToString());
            Response.TransmitFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
            //Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
            //Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          msg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Tell me if my solution helped you !

Answer (score 0):

If your path is correct just use this:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + e.CommandArgument));
```

Instead of:

```
Response.TransmitFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
```